# How do I Convert this Ajax Post request to C#

Tags: c#, ajax

I'm making a project in c# to get a facebook ID from any facebook URL. I an API that can helps but the code is using this Ajax POST code:

```
        // get facebook id
    $('#get-facebook-id').submit(function(event) {

        $('#answer').html("<b>Working for you...</b>");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://codeofaninja.com/tools/get-facebook-id-answer.php',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#answer').html(data);
            $('#page_url_tb').val('')
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "Posting failed. Please try again." );
        });

        return false;
    });
```

I'm trying to make my own code but is giving me an error. My code and my error down bellow.

```
private string getFbAccountID(string facebookurl)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://codeofaninja.com/tools/get-facebook-id-answer.php");

        var postData = "page_url="+facebookurl;
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return responseString;
    }
```

Error:

```
    <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: page_url in <b>/home/100661.cloudwaysapps.com/rpxdhcedbx/public_html/tools/get-facebook-id-answer.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>/home/100661.cloudwaysapps.com/rpxdhcedbx/public_html/tools/get-facebook-id-answer.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<p>There was an error. Please try a different input.</p>
```

This is always giving me this error. I hope someone can helps me

Comment: Where specifically is that error coming from?

Comment: Error updated, please check the post

Comment: If that is the response coming from the service you're integrating with then it sounds like you need to contact whoever maintains that service.  They're returning PHP errors to users.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're working on [this exercise](https://codeofaninja.com/tools/get-facebook-id). :)

But to answer your question, you're not URL encoding `facebookurl`.

If you use one of the example Facebook URLs on their page, and watch the network traffic using the developer tools in the browser (F12), you will see this as the form data being sent: `page_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FAndrew-Garfield%2F166865773328160`

jQuery's [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function does that for you.

In C#, you can use [`WebUtility.UrlEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode):

```
var postData = "page_url=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(facebookurl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an alternative using System.Net.WebClient, it will make your code leaner:

```
private string getFbAccountID(string facebookurl)
{
    using (var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var formValues = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
        {
            { "page_url", facebookurl }
        };

        var responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(
            "https://codeofaninja.com/tools/get-facebook-id-answer.php",
            formValues
            );

        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
    }
}
```